# Como hago para contabilizar en google calcs desde otra hoja

Tags: funciones, google-hoja-de-cálculo, libreoffice-calc

tendía pensado utilizar google calcs para gestionar mis gastos económicos, se que existen plantillas pero quería intentar crear una por mi mismo. El problema es el siguiente, yo tengo de una hoja llamada 'Todo', los datos de facturas, por ejemplo este:

```
Dia de compra   Asunto  Precio  Categoría
9/01/2020       Luz     45      Facturas
6/02/2020       Gas     12      Facturas
```

Y quiero que todos los precios de la misma categoría se sumen en una tabla en otra hoja, pero obviamente, separado por meses, por eso el día de compra. Tenia pensado utilizar esta formula para poder filtrar los datos

```
=IF(A2<=Todo!$B$2:$B<A3;SUMIF(Todo!$E$1:$E;$B1;Todo!$D$1:$D);"Sin gastos")
```

El problema es que me devuelve en la casilla 'Sin gastos' cuando obviamente hay gastos. Las columnas con fechas tienen el formato de fecha así que no entiendo el problema.

Para que se vea mejor paso dos imágenes
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Si alguien tiene alguna idea de una posible solución lo agradecería. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui te dejo todo el listo de ordenes que hay : https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=es

Analizador  CONVERTIR   CONVERTIR(valor, unidad_inicio, unidad_fin)

Analizador  TO_DATE TO_DATE(valor)

y hay mucho mas